# Python Twisted run CLI script from website

Tags: python, python-3.x, twisted

I am wanting to call python scripts that I have currently built from a web interface.  I was wondering if twisted can do this or if there is a better way to do this? Really looking for a guide or document on this so i can build this.

**Below is an example of what would happen when a user visits the webpage:**

```
Welcome, enter the IP you want to ping:

    Submit
```

Hitting the Submit button would call the below script and pass the IP put in the webpage to the script. (python3 ping.py 192.168.66.5)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import subprocess

ip = sys.argv[1]

ping =subprocess.Popen(('ping -c 3 ' + ip),shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
pingresult = str(ping.communicate()).split('\\n')

for p in pingresult:
    print(p)
```

Output i would like to see on the webpage would look something like this on the webpage:

```
64 bytes from 192.168.66.5: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.020 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.66.5: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.015 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.66.5: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.017 ms

--- 192.168.66.5 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1998ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.015/0.017/0.020/0.004 ms
```

Is this something that can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible and [Twisted has documentation on running processes](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/process.html). If your script is as simple as what you have, then you should consider just using Twisted's `reactor.spawnProcess()` function.

Comment: Thank you I will look into it, and the scripts are much more complicated, but I just made that as an example. :)